# Why push notification works with VPN over cellular data not on Wifi?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wifi, vpn, cellular-network

I am looking for an explanation, which i googled multiple ways and couldn't find one.

Scenario #1: Apple push notification **is not** getting delivered to iPhone when Cisco VPN is connected over **Wifi**.

Scenario #2: Apple push notification **is** getting delivered to iPhone when Cisco VPN is connected over **cellular data**. (Wifi turned off)

Can someone help me understand this?

I am not looking for how to make it work over Wifi :) but to understand why above scenario work the way it is. I may not able to get details about how the VPN server is setup.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the WiFi on some kind of corporate network? I saw the same thing when I was behind a corporate firewall.